# How to Create nested objects in isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I want to create a nested struture on my nested scope inside a directive like this:

```
angular.module('myAddress').directive('myAddress', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        controller: 'myAddressController',
        templateUrl: 'my-address.html',
        scope: {
            address: {
                'form': '=addressForm',
                'model': '=addressModel'
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

But I get an exception that undefined is not a function that I don't get if I remove the address nesting.

How do I put attribute arguments inside a named key on my scope?

Also, If I define $scope.address via the controller it doesn't work as well. But what will execute first? The scope: { 'form' = 'addressForm'} part in my directive or the controller's $scope.form?

Comment: It seems like you're not passing a function as the second parameter to directive() as maybe you should. You're passing an array, like when you want Angular to inject stuff into your directive, but you do not inject anything. If nothing else, the array brackets are not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `scope` property you define which `$scope` variables should pass to the directive `scope` and the type of data-binding.

If you want to create an nested structure within the directive `$scope`, you could create it in the directive `controller` function.

For example:

```
angular.module('myAddress').directive('myAddress', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    controller: 'myAddressController',
    templateUrl: 'my-address.html',
    scope: {
            addressForm: '=',  // Two-way databinding
            addressModel: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
         $scope.address = {
            form: $scope.addressForm,
            model: $scope.addressModel
         }
    },
    link: function($scope,$element,$attributes){
           //Your code here
    }
  };
}]);
```

You can also, define `$scope.address` in the module controller `scope`. Then your `scope` property in the directive should be look like this

```
scope: { 
       address: '='
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Another question is: Does your directive need an dedicated scope? If not you could set the `scope` property `false`. Then your directive can access the `$scope` variables in your module controller.

Comment: I think it's a great idea, but I would put it into the controller instead so you have one place where you handle all the scope-stuff. This would have the added benefit that the controller declares every scope variable, including the directive arguments.

If you agree, could you update the answer and move the linking code to the controller so I can accept the answer?

Comment: I literally meant for you to take the link function and put it into the controller. `controller: function($scope) {...}`.

Comment: Yeah, I want an isolated scope since I think a non-isolated scope is kinda broken.